# Update MySQL record twice using 'CASE'

Tags: mysql, case

I am working on an accountant software , some times the invoice contain the same item id twice (every one with its unique serial number) .. so after selling the two items I need its quantity equals quantity-1

I am using this statement for updating some records

```
    UPDATE `table1` SET `quantity` = CASE
    WHEN id = 1 THEN quantity-1
    WHEN id = 1 THEN quantity-1
    END
    WHERE id in (1)
```

after updating using this statement ,the value of `quantity` ignores the second statement

How can I solve this ?

**EDIT**

The answer

Thank You ... I found the trick by myself

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `quantity` = CASE
WHEN id = (1*(1/1)) THEN quantity-1
WHEN id = (1*(2/2)) THEN quantity-1
WHEN id = (1*(3/3)) THEN quantity-1
END
WHERE id in (1)
```

the record will be updated 3 times by the same query

why I need This ?

because my software accepts that the user can add the same (Product ID) many times in the same invoice so I need the query to update the quantity many times in the same statement for one (Product ID)

Comment: You probably need to structure your query differently, but since it's not clear what you're trying to achieve here it's going to be difficult to suggest how.

Comment: What do you want it to be? Do you want it to be 1 or 2? You're asking it to pick for you, and computers don't work that way.

Comment: what does this even mean......? _some time my single query contains the same id twice 'LIKE THIS'_

Comment: see my updated answer... i think that is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might actually be what you want.  I have `id=1` in my table 3 times, so `mcount` is set equal to `3`.  The row for `ID=2` was not updated because of the where condition.

```
update table1  
       join (select id, count(*) as ct from table1 group by id) as ct_tbl 
   set mcount = ct_tbl.ct  
 where table1.id=1 

 mysql> select * from table1;
+------+--------+
| id   | mcount |
+------+--------+
|    1 |      3 |
|    1 |      3 |
|    1 |      3 |
|    2 |      0 |
+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

I don't want to hijack the other answer because it's totally correct but I think it needs more explanation.

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `mcount` = CASE
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 2
    END
    WHERE id in (1)
```

that is the equivalent of... (psuedo)

```
in the table table1 
where the id = 1 
   if id = 1 then set mcount = 1 
   if id = 1 then set mcount = 2
```

Because of the `where` statement, we already know that we will only select rows where `id=1`.  Those `if` statements will just overwrite each other.  I really don't know what you're after but normally...

the following will add one to `mcount`

```
UPDATE `table1` 
   SET `mcount` = mcount + 1; 
 WHERE id in (1)
```

the following will toggle `mcount` values

```
UPDATE `table1` 
   SET `mcount` = CASE WHEN mcount = 1 THEN 2
                       WHEN mcount = 2 THEN 1 END
 WHERE id in (1)
```

the following will toggle `mcount` values

```
UPDATE `table1` 
   SET `mcount` = CASE WHEN other_field = 'Y' THEN 1
                       WHEN other_field = 'N' THEN 2 END
 WHERE id in (1)
```

working with multiple `ID` values...

```
UPDATE `table1` 
   SET `mcount` = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1
                       WHEN id = 2 THEN 2
                       WHEN id = 3 THEN 3 END
 WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

which is the same as...

```
UPDATE `table1` 
   SET `mcount` = id
 WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

now the real question is... *if ID=1 then what should mcount be?*

also....

```
set @row:=0; 
update table1 
       set mcount = @row:=@row+1  
where  id = 1;
```

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+------+--------+
| id   | mcount |
+------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |
|    1 |      2 |
|    1 |      3 |
|    2 |      0 |
+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you gloomy.penguin for your explanation response

first I need you to know why I need this
I am working on an accountant software , some times the invoice contain the same item id twice (every one with its unique serial number) .. so after selling the two items I need its quantity equals itself-1

Answer (score 1):

Your statement has the same condition for each case, always will return 1 (first statement), the second statement will be ignored because it is the same condition.

Comment: Thank You ... I fount the trick by myself 

UPDATE `table1` SET `quantity` = CASE
    WHEN id = (1) THEN quantity-1
    WHEN id = (1*1) THEN quantity-1
    WHEN id = (1*1*1) THEN quantity-1
    END
    WHERE id in (1)

the record will be updated 3 times by the same query

Answer (score 1):

Thank You ... I found the trick by myself

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `quantity` = CASE
WHEN id = (1*(1/1)) THEN quantity-1
WHEN id = (1*(2/2)) THEN quantity-1
WHEN id = (1*(3/3)) THEN quantity-1
END
WHERE id in (1)
```

the record will be updated 3 times by the same query